# JMS serializer - how to ignore (not exclude) property (already json)

Tags: php, jms-serializer

i have an object that stores a json string in one of the properties. And i don't want it to be serialized again. Is there a reasonable way to ignore it ?

PostSerialize event might be an option (revert it back), but that's dirty. I'd prefer a cleaner approach.

Comment: Please share what you have tried thus far, preferably with a [mcve].

Comment: Well, i've read the whole documentation - https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotation and looked for answers all over the internet, and couldn't find the answer, so i'm hoping someone has had this problem before and could help me out.

No need for an example on my side, i think.